# How does the __proto__ accessor property manipulate the 'hidden' [[prototype]] property and can we see the code it uses?

Tags: javascript

I know that `__proto__` is deprecated to use in code. However the Chrome console still uses `__proto__` to show properties that aren't 'own' properties and this looks helpful to me.

This [article](https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance) states objects have a 'hidden, special' property described as `[[prototype]]` which returns an object (referred to as 'prototype') or null.

It also states `__proto__` is as an accessor property that returns and can mutate this `[[prototype]]` property.

(Although accessor properties don't have values so it seems strange to me that Chrome displays `__proto__` as if it points towards an object).

Based on this, can I guess that in `{}`, there exists a hidden property `[[prototype]]` that points towards an object that contains|points towards `Object.prototype`?

And our access to this hidden property is somehow mediated through the `__proto__` accessor property?

If I wanted to see more how this works, are there any suggestions?

Finally, as JavaScript Object-Orientated programmers is it even necessary to know how the `__proto__` accessor property manipulates the prototype object? I seem to get by without knowing too much about it.

Comment: "*I know that `__proto__` is deprecated to use in code.*" - and you also know about `Object.create`, `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`?

Comment: "*However the Chrome console still uses `__proto__` to show properties that aren't 'own' properties and this looks helpful to me.*" - well, they could use any designator for displaying, even [show it as *\[\[prototype\]\]*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=817305) but they didn't. Firefox does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Although accessor properties don't have values so it seems strange to me that Chrome displays **proto** as if it points towards an object).

The value the accessor returns points to the object. But more importantly, Chrome isn't using the property at all; it's just using that as a means of showing you what the prototype of the object is. It even shows you that for objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype` and so don't have the `__proto__` accessor. Example:

```js
// An object with no prototype
const noProto = Object.create(null);
console.log(noProto);

// An object with a prototype, but not one that inherits from Object.prototype:
const obj = Object.create(noProto);
console.log(obj);

// `obj` doesn't have `__proto__` at all
console.log("__proto__" in obj); // false

// Normally, objects do:
console.log("__proto__" in {});  // true
```

When I run that, once I've expanded the display for the two objects, I get:

[image]

Notice how `__proto__` is displayed (showing that `obj` inherits from `noProto`) but `obj` doesn't have a `__proto__` property.

> Based on this, can I guess that in {}, there exists a hidden property [[prototype]] that points towards an object that contains|points towards Object.prototype?

It's not a hidden property, it's an [internal slot](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots), but yes.

> And our access to this hidden property is somehow mediated through the **proto** accessor property? Indirectly. The accessor property is literally just this on `Object.prototype`:

```
{
    get() {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    },
    set(p) {
        return Object.setPrototypeOf(this, p);
    },
    configurable: true,
}
```

So when you read from `__proto__`, you're calling `Object.getPrototypeOf`, which is what reads the internal [[Prototype]] internal slot.

> Finally, as JavaScript Object-Orientated programmers is it even necessary to know how the **proto** accessor property manipulates the prototype object? I seem to get by without knowing too much about it.

It's rare to need to manipulate the prototypes of existing objects, and it may not be optimized well if you do it, so it's best avoided (whether you do it via `__proto__` — which you shouldn't — or the `Object` methods). Sometimes you need to *get* the prototype of an existing object, and `Object.getPrototypeOf` is good for that, but in general, if you're reaching for `Object.setPrototypeOf`, it's best to stop and think whether you should have created that object with a different prototype to start with. :-)

Comment: The first point I've learned is that Chrome's `__proto__` thing that appears in objects does not represent any real JS code. It is just a Chrome thing that shows you what's in that object's 'hidden, special' prototype property. Secondly, are you saying there exists `Object.prototype.__proto__` but you just can't see it on Chrome?

Comment: @tonitone120 - It definitely represents something real, it's just as far as I can tell, devtools shows you [[Prototype]], not the actual `__proto__` property, even though it labels it `__proto__`. They've probably been doing that since before `__proto__` was standardized and haven't changed it. (Changing it could be awkward, since you can have a property called [[Prototype]]...) So we're in this only-slightly-odd place where it's using that label for [[Prototype]] rather than the actual `__proto__` property.

Comment: *"Secondly, are you saying there exists Object.prototype.__proto__ but you just can't see it on Chrome?"* Yes you can. If you type `console.log(Object.prototype);`, Chrome will show you lots of stuff, including `get __proto__` and `set __proto__`. It doesn't show you `__proto__` because, again, it uses that to label [[Prototype]], and `Object.prototype` doesn't have one (`__proto__: null` would have been okay too). You can also use `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "__proto__"));` to see the definition (sans code) of the accessor property.